# how to block a function until previous one is finished? nodejs

Tags: node.js

have a for loop with a dynamic value that could be small to big, I want to make sure one call to search is finished before the next one can start. how do I do that? I've read about process.nextTick and setImmediate but I'm unsure how to use either in this context.

```
function search(x) {
      dns.resolve(x, function (err, addresses) {
           if (!err) {
                res.send("bad");
           } else {
                res.send("good");
           }
      });
}

for(a = 0; a < queries.length; a++) {
    query = queries[a];
    search(query);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually just use event emitters to make it all synchronous so I can still work within the asynchronous environment mindset. In my code below, whenever a DNS resolve gets finished, it produces an event that is listened to by the search function and lets it know to fire a new search. Plus, you get to learn how to create your own Event Emitters, which are awesome.

If you want to make it asynchronous for a certain size of the domain name array, you can create a denominator variable and use the modulus operator to send asynchronous in chunks and only fire a synchronous event(to clear the async buffer) whenever the modulus reaches 0.

```
// program that uses event emitters to create sync code in an async env

var dns = require('dns')                                //dns from core
var eventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter       //Event Emitter from core

var ee = new eventEmitter;      //make an Event Emitter object

var queries = ['yahoo.com','google.com','james.com'];

ee.on('next', next_search);     //create a listener for an event we define

// our listening function that executes on our defined 'next' event
function next_search() {
        search(queries[a]);
        if(queries.length == a) process.exit(0);
        ++a;
}

// the actual search function that uses DNS
function search(x) {
        dns.resolve(x, function (err) {
                if (!err) {
                        //res.send("bad");
                        console.log('bad: ' + x)
                        ee.emit('next')
                } else {
                        //res.send("good");
                        console.log('good: ' + x)
                        ee.emit('next')
                }
        });
}


// global variable to keep track of our name queue length
var a = 0;

// kick it all off
next_search()
```

Comment: how can I use this as a webapp? tried doing this but node shuts itself down after one search http://pastebin.com/UWXikLt7

Answer (score 7):

There are a few libraries out there that can help you organize the execution of asynchronous code.  [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async) is the one I use and it's [eachSeries()](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachseriesarr-iterator-callback) is useful here:

```
function search(x,callback) {
  dns.resolve(x, function (err, addresses) {
    if (!err) {
      res.send("bad");
    } else {
      res.send("good");
    }
    callback(err);
  });
}

async.eachSeries(queries,
  function(query,callback) {
    search(query,callback);
  },
  function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log("we had an error");
    }
  }
);
```

Note that Async will call the final callback as soon as one of the iterations has an error so if you don't want to stop there, you'll need to call `callback()` in the `search()` instead of `callback(err)`.

UPDATE (without using a library):

If you don't want to use a library, you could implement it yourself like this:

```
function searchInternal(queries, idx, callback) {
  if(idx === queries.length) {
    callback();
    return;
  }

  dns.resolve(queries[idx], function (err, addresses) {
    if (!err) {
      res.send("bad");
    } else {
      res.send("good");
    }
    searchInternal(queries, idx+1, callback);
  });
}

function searchAll(queries, callback) {
  searchInternal(queries, 0, callback);
}

searchAll(queries, function() {
  console.log("all done now");
});
```

Note, this code isn't tested, and probably isn't the *best* implementation, but thats why we use libraries.

Comment: that's cool, but is there a way to do it without a plugin, with native nodejs functionality?

Comment: @archytect: I updated the answer with a sample implementation without using a library.

Comment: Don't be afraid of libraries. It is very common in Node.js to rely on libraries.

Comment: nothing's wrong with using plugins, I just wanna learn how it would have been done without plugins instead of going the easy route and using one to achieve the same thing. :)

thanks

Comment: I think your non-library code is still async, isn't it? Maybe I'm missing something though.

Comment: @EhevuTov: Its async in the sense that code after `searchAll` will be execute before all the searches finish, but the actual searches _appear_ synchronous because I'm calling the next `searchInternal` in the callback of the previous one (i.e. after it completes).  I like your `EventEmitter` approach though!

Comment: Thank you, @go-oleg. I didn't mean to steal your thunder though. Yours is a well-programmed answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently created simpler abstraction called **wait.for** to call async functions in sync mode (based on node-fibers). It is at:

https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor

Using **wait.for**, you can make the calls to dns.resolve to execute sequentially.

**wait.for** allows you to call any standard nodejs async function, as if it were a sync function, without blocking node's event loop. You can code sequentially when you need it.

using **wait.for** your code will be:

```
for(a = 0; a < queries.length; a++) {
  try {
    addresses = wait.for(dns.resolve,queries[a]);
    res.send('good');
  }
  catch(err){
    res.send('bad');
  }

}//end for
```